# How many .java files is common in a project

Tags: java

I am a newbie in Java, and I would like to know what is normal coding best practice when creating more complex programs.

Question: Is it common to add all your code (classes, methods, objects, etc) in only 1 .java file?   Or, as programs get more complex do developers use more than 1 .java files (2 or more) which hold many methods and the main .java file with the main() function make calls to those other files and work with the returned data?

Comment: One meeeellion!  *puts pinky in mouth*  Yeah seriously there's no good answer to this.  Depends on the project.  It is certainly not common to add all your code in one file, but how many files are appropriate depends on the size of the project.

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141855.html

Comment: Why do not you go to https://github.com/ and see for yourself? Here is an example: https://github.com/apache/commons-lang

Comment: Hundreds of files isn't uncommon for a medium-sized project.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick response.  Those were the answers I was looking for.  Although opinion based, it was enough feedback to answer my question.  Thanks for the links for further information.

Comment: When starting out writing a package or program, i find it easier to declare all of the the classes in a single file until they become substantial enough to merit their own file.

Comment: Searching open-source projects is a good way to learn this and many other things. For an example of a huge project, look at Java itself in the form of [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) hosted in a [Mercurial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) repository, such as [Java 11](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad).

Comment: How long is a piece of string?

Comment: I would recommend you to separate your code based on the objects which you are creating. Suppose you are writing a library management program for managing books and their authors, it would be logical to separate your class files like Books, Authors and Driver class (main method class) so that you can take advantage of OOPs features.

Comment: and just for the record: in case you consider the answer helpful, you might want to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The language itself gives a bit of guidance: a *public* class A needs to go into A.java. So each public class requires you to put it into a separate file.

Of course, you could then add as many inner or non public classes to that file as you want. But that is rather regarded bad practice. The commonly used Google coding standard for Java suggests to **always** have exactly **one** top level class per file. Not 2, not 5: one.

Finally, you have to understand: a complex network of simple (small) classes is to be preferred over a simple network of large, complicated classes! You always strive to have small classes, responsible for "one thing".